# update audit fields in a many-to-many Entity Framework model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a legacy database with a many-to-many relationship like the following:

```
    public class Post  
    {
        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        ...
    }

    public class Tag 
    {
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

with the many-to-many relationship tracked in a 'PostTagLink' table.

Normally it is easy to use Code First to express the many-to-many relationship more or less implicitly, i.e. update the 'PostTagLink' table when a relationship is added or removed, but without actually having a 'PostTagLink' entity explicitly defined.

Audit fields on Tags and Posts can be updated easily by the DbContext when changes are saved:

```
    public abstract class MyAuditableEntityContext : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            string currentUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

            foreach (DbEntityEntry<IAuditableEntity> changeEntry in base.ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditableEntity>())
            {
                if (changeEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    changeEntry.Entity.CreatedBy = currentUser;
                    changeEntry.Entity.RevisedBy = currentUser;
                }
                else if (changeEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    changeEntry.Entity.RevisedBy = currentUser;
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

But what if the 'PostTagLink' table also includes audit fields?

The only solution I can see it to include a PostTagLink entity in the model (with many-to-one relationships back to Tag and Post) so I can access the audit fields in the DbContext SaveChanges method.

But adding these extra entities makes working with the model awkward. Clients and queries have to work the the 'link' entities directly instead of Entity Framework handling the relationship changes automatically.

**The question:**  Is there some Entity-Framework-ninja technique where I could intercept the changes to many-to-many relationships and update the link table audit fields as necessary, without having to explicitly include 'link' entities in the model?

(Again - this is a legacy database and there is little I can do to change it, so I'd like to avoid adding stored procedures or any other logic to the database.)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this.  What's the cure?" 
Doctor:  "Don't do that."

I'm going to answer my own question as 'there is no answer'.  As I've seen others advise in comments on related StackOverflow questions - I think it will ultimately be better to just include the 'link' entities explicitly in the model.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly, when you add an item to one of the collections and save the entity, you need to set a CreatedBy field in the many-to-many table. You can execute raw sql using DbContext.Database.SqlCommand to update the link table audit fields. [How to execute raw sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907).

So how to intercept the changes?

These answers might help: [EF4 Audit changes of many to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4683065/150342) and [Entity Framework: Tracking changes to FK associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6048921/150342)

**EDIT:**

For reference here is the [original example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I posted that may have led you to believe that you had to put sql into your model

Comment: Thanks Colin. I think injecting SQL into the model would be a cure worse than the disease in my case.  Although I suspect that method or using SQL to directly call a stored procedure are the only real options in EF5.  Perhaps when EF6 and support for sprocs in the model is available, I'll be able to call a sproc from the model after detecting relationship changes.

Comment: Sorry. I gave you a link to a poor example using the ObjectContext in a model. You don't need to put the code in a model and you can do it using the DBContext. I will amend the link in my question